# How do I replace a class with 2 possible implementations or subclasses

Tags: oop, solid-principles

I have a csv parser application that uses a Header type to parse the headers of the csv and save them in member variables.

CSVParser —-> uses Header (name, region, price)

Now, I have a new requirement where I need to support a new Header type -> name, region, tax

How do I support this?

Approach 1
I thought of having Header (name, region) and a,

- PriceHeader extends Header (price)
- TaxHeader extends Header (tax)

But I need to change the code in CSVParser to determine which Header type I’d like to use.

Approach 2
Create an interface CSVParser that is implemented by A. PriceCSVParser and B. TaxCSVParser. They both use PriceHeader and TaxHeader respectively. Then I need to change upstream of course to determine which CSVParser to use.
The CSVParser needs to validate headers before beginning to parse. The validation depends on which Header fields apply.

I am new to OOP and have looked at the SOLID design principles, but am completely new to design patterns.

Question in short - how do I design my application when I have to use 2 type of model objects like the Header. Sorry for not posting code snippets. Posting this over phone.

Tried Approach 1 - inheritance but I feel like this violates a principle where the subclasses should be substitutable for the super class. Then in Approach 2 - I also can try interfaces.
I understand that the question is subjective and that a bad design would “work” but I want to use this problem as a way to learn better design

Answer (score 0):

If you have very similar methods with different signatures, you can create a method with same name. This depends on language, but it is called overloading.

So, for different purposes, you need different methods. Which is main reason why methods exists.

> But I need to change the code in CSVParser to determine which Header type I’d like to use.

For this concern you do not need any new class. You are still writing code about cvs parser. You do not have to use OOP concepts just because you can. Just write a simple third and main method to decide which parser method you need. This method should navigate between parsers. So, if you need a third parser, you just edit this method to reach that 3rd parser.

Creating new interfaces, classes can complicate things if you don't need them for any purposes. Try to find simplest solution. Hope it clarify few things.